# Bash script - decode encoded string to byte array

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am new to bash scripting and I am writing a small script where I need to decode the encoded string and convert it to a byte array.

```
my_array=(`echo "dGVzdA==" | base64 -d`)
```

when I print the size of the array it's showing as 1 instead of 4.

```
echo "${#my_array[*]}"
```

Question - will not `base64 -d` convert to a byte array? There is an equivalent java code where it does for me:

```
byte [] b = Base64.getDecoder().decode("dGVzdA==");
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Bash doesn't have a `byte` type, or [any other types](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/untyped.html#:~:text=Unlike%20many%20other%20programming%20languages,a%20variable%20contains%20only%20digits.). Vars are strings.

Comment: It's not encrypted, it's encoded.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> to byte array

There are no "byte arrays" in shells. You can basically choose from two types of variables:

- a string
- an array of strings (bash extension, not available on all shells)

How you *interpret* the data is up to you, the shell can only store strings. Bash has an extension called "bash arrays" that allows to create an array. Note that strings are zero terminated - it's impossible to store the zero byte.

> Question - will it not base64 -d converts into byte array ?

The string `dGVzdA==` is base64 encoded string `test`. So you can *convert* the string `dGVzdA==` to the string `test`:

```
$ echo "dGVzdA==" | base64 -d
test# no newline is printed after test, as the newline is not in input
```

> Any thoughts ?

You could convert the **string** `test` to a **string** that contains *the  representation of each byte as hexadecimal number*, typically with `xxd`:

```
$ echo "dGVzdA==" | base64 -d | xxd -p
74657374
```

Now you could insert a newline after each two characters in the *string* and read the output as a *newline separated list of strings* into an array:

```
$ readarray -t array < <(echo "dGVzdA==" | base64 -d | xxd -p -c1)
$ declare -p array
declare -a array=([0]="74" [1]="65" [2]="73" [3]="74")
```

Each element of the array is one byte in the input represented as a string that contains a number in base16. This may be as close as you can get to a "byte array".

Comment: "Note that strings are zero terminated - it's impossible to store the zero byte." - you can store a null byte in a file: `printf "\0" >somefile` and you can send a null byte through a pipe: `printf "a\0b" | xargs -0 -n1 echo`

Answer (score 2):

```sh
#!/bin/bash

read -r -a my_array < <(echo 'dGVzdA==' | base64 -d | sed 's/./& /g')
echo "${#my_array[@]}"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also access individual characters in a string variable to do this.

```
$: v=$( echo "dGVzdA==" | base64 -d )
$: my_array=( $( for(( i=0; i<${#v}; i++ )); do echo "${v:i:1}"; done ) )
$: echo ${my_array[2]}
s
```

This isn't a one-liner, but aside from the `base64` call I think it's all done in the parser.

Answer (score 1):

### Introduction

Syntax:

```bash
 encoded='dGVzdA=='
 myVar=$(base64 -d <<<"$encoded")
```

Work fine, but if you plan to work with a lot of encoded strings, doing:

```bash
base64Decoder() {
    local -n _result=${2:-B64Decoded}
    _result=$(base64 -d <<<"$1")
}
```

Will be enough:

```bash
base64Decoder $encoded decoded
echo $decoded
```

```
test
```

But having to fork to `base64 -d` for each operation could become heavy...

### *Pure bash* BASE64 decoder function.

As this question stand for

> #### Bash script - decode encoded string to byte array

to be used as *library function*, there is a very efficient pure bash way. This is a lot quicker, **for small strings**!

```bash
#!/bin/bash
# Base64 decoder - pure bash function
# <C> 2024 F-Hauri.ch - felix@f-hauri.ch
# Licensed under terms of GPL v3. www.gnu.org
# shellcheck disable=SC2154  # not assigned 'myVar' ??
shopt -s extglob

declare -a B64=( {A..Z} {a..z} {0..9} + / '=' )
declare -Ai 'B64R=()'
for i in "${!B64[@]}"; do B64R["${B64[i]}"]=i%64; done
# shellcheck disable=SC2034 # Unused 'B64R' ??
declare -r B64R
unset B64
```

```bash
b64dec() {
    local _4B _Tail _hVal _v _opt OPTIND
    local -i iFd _24b _ar
    while getopts "av:" _opt; do case $_opt in
        a) _ar=1;; v) _v=${OPTARG};; *) return 1;; esac; done
    shift $((OPTIND-1))
    if [[ $_v ]];then local -n _res=${_v}; else local _res; fi
    if [[ $1 ]]; then        exec {iFd}<<<"$1"      # Open Input FD from string
    else            exec {iFd}<&0   ; fi    # Open Input FD from STDIN
    _res=()
    while read -rn4 -u $iFd _4B; do
        if [[ "$_4B" ]]; then
            _Tail=$_4B
            _24b=" B64R['${_4B::1}'] << 18 | B64R['${_4B:1:1}'] << 12 |
                   B64R['${_4B:2:1}'] << 6 | B64R['${_4B:3:1}'] "
            printf -v _hval %02x\  $((_24b>>16)) $((_24b>>8&255)) $((_24b&255))
            read -ra _hval <<<"$_hval"
            _res+=("${_hval[@]}")
        fi
    done
    exec {iFd}<&-
    _Tail=${_Tail##*([^=])}
    while [[ $_Tail ]]; do
        unset "_res[-1]"
        _Tail=${_Tail:1}
    done
    ((_ar==0)) && printf -v _res %b "${_res[@]/#/\\x}" && _res=("${_res[0]}")
    [[ -z $_v ]] && echo "${_res[@]}"
}
```

For handling binary datas, I use *array of bytes values* because it's the only way for handling null bytes (`\x0`) in bash. I use *hexadecimal* values in order to make conversion to binary easy by using `printf %b ${varname[@]/#/\\x}` syntaxe.

> ```
> Usage: b64dec [-v varname] [-a] [string]
>     -v VARNAME  Assign result to $VARNAME instead of print them on STDOUT
>     -a          Return an array of hexadecimal values for hangling binary
> If no "string" are submited as argument, b64dec will wait for input on STDIN.
> ```

Then:

```bash
echo -n '1 '; b64dec 'dGVzdA=='
```

```
1 test
```

```bash
echo -n '2 ' b64dec <<<'dGVzdA=='
```

```
2 test
```

```bash
b64dec -v myVar 'dGVzdA=='
echo "3 $myVar"
```

```
3 test
```

```bash
b64dec -av myVar 'dGVzdA=='
printf -v str %b "${myVar[@]/#/\\x}"
printf '4 %s <= [%s].\n' "$str" "${myVar[*]}"
```

```
4 test <= [74 65 73 74].
```

```bash
lstr='H4sIAAAAAAACA/NIzcnJVyjPL8pJU'
for str in ${lstr}{eQCAEHkqbINAAAA,VTkAgAYI85FDgAAAA==,VRU5AIAj62OVw8AAAA=}; do
    b64dec -v test -a <<<"$str"
    zcat < <(printf %b "${test[@]/#/\\x}")
done
```

```
Hello world!
Hello world!!
Hello world!!!
```

```bash
b64dec -av myVar < <( seq 1 100 | column | gzip | base64 )
gzip -d < <(printf %b "${myVar[@]/#/\\x}")
```

```
1      11      21      31      41      51      61      71      81      91
2      12      22      32      42      52      62      72      82      92
3      13      23      33      43      53      63      73      83      93
4      14      24      34      44      54      64      74      84      94
5      15      25      35      45      55      65      75      85      95
6      16      26      36      46      56      66      76      86      96
7      17      27      37      47      57      67      77      87      97
8      18      28      38      48      58      68      78      88      98
9      19      29      39      49      59      69      79      89      99
10     20      30      40      50      60      70      80      90      100
```

Where `$myVar` do hold a lot of *null bytes*:

```bash
declare -p myVar
```

```
declare -a myVar=([0]="1f" [1]="8b" [2]="08" [3]="00" [4]="00" [5]="00" [6]="00"
 [7]="00" [8]="00" [9]="03" [10]="05" [11]="c1" [12]="49" [13]="01" [14]="00" [1
5]="30" [16]="08" [17]="04" [18]="b1" [19]="f7" [20]="54" [21]="0d" [22]="cb" [2
...
"67" [147]="c8" [148]="ec" [149]="7d" [150]="3d" [151]="d9" [152]="29" [153]="b9
" [154]="24" [155]="01" [156]="00" [157]="00")
```

Comment: Full rewrite 2024!! New function 100% pure bash! With two nice options `-a` for output an array of hexadecimal values and `-v` to store result into a variable.